# Ean13, 5 - digit add-on, where can i find instruction how to generate addon?

Tags: delphi, barcode

I cannot find the information in the internet, how to draw 5 digit add-on.
I have already had ean 13 algorithm, but cannot find add-on?

Has anyone of you come across it somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: i am rather looking for algorithm or source code example. Anyway an add-on is an EAn13' suplement. Can be 2 or 5 digit. I am not interested in commercial libraries, just a piece of code or explanation how it is done. Thanks :)

Comment: I found an [detailed explination](http://www.barcodeisland.com/upcext.phtml) of how the supplemental barcodes are encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rather old barcode library from Andreas Schmidt called *Barcode Component*. It can be found at [Torry's](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?s=93) ([direct download](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=1836)). It comes with source and can generate the 5-digit addon (and many more).

To actually make it compile you have to fix 2 Unicode-related issues, but then it works. The barcode type you have to look for in Barcode.pas is `bcCodeUPC_Supp5` - that's the addon (or supplement).

So this is one source you can pull knowledge from. Kudos if you understand the source, though ;)